# Neo4j Traverser not working probably

Tags: traversal, neo4j

I have the following tree:

```
1-[HAS]->2-[HASSUBPAGE]->3-[HASSUBPAGE]->4
```

Now I want to traverse this tree starting at `4` and go up to `1` with this traverser (postng to `/db/data/node/4/traverse/node`):

```
{"order":"breadth_first","uniqueness":"node_path","relationships":[{"type":"HASSUBPAGE","direction":"in"},{"type":"HAS","direction":"in"}]}
```

But it stops at node `3` so all I get is node `3`.
Any Ideas, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide the max_depth parameter, as it defaults to 1 (to prevent infinite traversals).

Please try that and report if it worked for you.

Comment: I could have sworn, that I added max_depth, anyway. Thank you.